# VisualForce code that's rendering line items of an order -- any way to exclude certain families and sub-families?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Here's my code:

```
<apex:repeat var="oi" value="{!relatedTo.OrderItems}">
    <apex:outputText value="{0,number,#,##0}">
    <apex:param value="{!oi.Quantity}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Let's say we have a product family of "in-person-event" and another of "online-subscription". Is there anyway to exclude those product line items from being generated?

Thanks!

Comment: you have to filter the OrderItems values in your controller/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `rendered` attribute here:

```
<apex:outputText
    rendered="{!oi.Product2.Family != 'A' && oi.Product2.Family != 'B'}"
    value="{0,number,#,##0}" />
```